# Options for writing Excel with Java

Tags: java, excel

I want to know what my options are for writing Excel files using Java. I know about JXL and [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). Are there others? And in your experience, which one is the best and which one is the most commonly used?

Answer (score 3):

Apache POI offers very low level handling which you may find difficulty in, both development and maintenance.

You can also look into JasperReports or iText.

I have worked with both jasper reports and itext, I would say jasper report with drag and drop packed in the ireport ide feature to be most maintenance friendly.

I support itext for its documentation and programmatic way of rendering an pdf or excel.

Answer (score 3):

you can check the following projects:

- [JExcel](http://www.teamdev.com/jexcel/index.jsf): a very good java Excel
     api project
- [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/): another java api for
        excel
- [openoffice.org API project](http://api.openoffice.org/) :   you could manipulate Excel files using theOpenOffice API in different programming languages (c++ ,java etc)
- ODF toolkit and jopendocument.org :  see [this article](http://othmanelmoulatblog.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/odf-toolkit-vs-jopendocument/) for more info  about these two project

Answer (score -1):

A simple implementation for exporting tabular data to Excel is to create a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.
Excel will open this up like a regular Excel-file.